# NodAffinity solution for pods running out of space

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob, argo-workflows

I have wrote a configuration file to run several cronJobs.
Each cronjob runs in a separate pod, and all the pods the in the same node.

This causes my a node out of space issue and as a solution I read about NodeAffinity.

I want to add the nodeAffinity to my cronjob, but I am struggling to understand the syntax and what should be under the labelSelector.

Here's what I wrote:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
serviceAccount: argo-events-sa
metadata:
  name: nightly-cron
  namespace: argo-events
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
              - web-store
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
  schedule: "0 1 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 0
  workflowSpec:
      ttlStrategy:
        secondsAfterCompletion: 10800 # 3 hours
      workflowTemplateRef:
        name: wf-e2e-test
      arguments:
        parameters:
          - name: test_repos
            value: |
              [
                { "repo": "svc1" },
                { "repo": "svc2" },
                { "repo": "svc3" },
                { "repo": "svc4" },
                { "repo": "svc5" },
                { "repo": "svc6" },
                { "repo": "svc7" }
              ] 
          - name: report_name_prefix
            value: "nightly-"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use *`nodeSelector`* instead.

**Attach label to the node**

`kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>`

e.g. `kubectl label nodes my-node app=web-store`

**Add a nodeSelector field to your pod configuration**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          nodeSelector:
            app: web-store
```

Even if `nodeSelector` will do the same simply, if you still want to use `nodeAffinity`, you should create and use the label for it just like in `nodeSelector` example.